# What's the best way to level at 19?

Tags: borderlands-2

What is the most efficient way to level fast? I'm on a quest that I always fail.  I am an assassin that mainly uses snipers, shotguns, revolvers, and SMGs, so let me know a good place to get good experience fast with those types of weapons.

Comment: Related, perhaps: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/98332/20456.  He's even the same level as you, so that should be perfect.

Comment: As a sidenote, please put more effort into your questions and answers.  Every single one of your questions and answers has had to be edited to add punctuation and clean up spelling.  Some minor errors are fine, as nobody's perfect, but we do expect you to attempt to put some effort into it.